# ASP.NET CORE How to Validate a Not Required Date?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I get a ModelState.IsValid with a date like 4/31/2021 (only 30 days in April) then my Convert.ToDateTime(form["StatusRangeFrom"]); throws an error.

I need either a null date or valid date. How can I check if the date is not valid and set the ModelState to not valid, and return to the view with the proper invalid date message?

Model:

```
    [Display(Name ="Date From")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StatusRangeFrom { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(IFormCollection form)
 {
 UserPreferences userPreferences = await _conn.UserPreferences.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.AccessID == Convert.ToInt32(form["AccessID"]));

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       if (form["StatusRangeFrom"].ToString() != "")
       {
           userPreferences.StatusRangeFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(form["StatusRangeFrom"]); // throws error on bad date
       }
       else
       {
           userPreferences.StatusRangeFrom = null;
    }
    
    
    await _conn.SaveChangesAsync();
```

View:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StatusRangeFrom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="date" asp-for="StatusRangeFrom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StatusRangeFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, it's working fine. It didn't allow me to reach the controller showing an error of invalid date. Can you share your whole view code?

Comment: The error is with: Convert.ToDateTime(form["StatusRangeFrom"]); with a bad date like 04/31/2021 because April has only 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I have created a sample, it seems that on the client side, it will validate the entered date is valid or not, if the date is invalid, it will prevent submit the form to the action, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CURDv.gif).

[image]

Then StatusViewModel.cs:

```
public class StatusViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date From")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StatusRangeFrom { get; set; }
}
```

The Create.cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication6.Data.StatusViewModel 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StatusRangeFrom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StatusRangeFrom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StatusRangeFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you disable the client side validation or doesn't use the Submit Form method to submit the form. According to your code, since you are getting the entered value via the `IFormCollection`. If that is the case, you could try to validate the date using the `DateTime.TryParse()` method. Sample code as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IFormCollection form)
    {
        StatusViewModel model = new StatusViewModel();
        model.Name = form["Name"];
        DateTime date;
        //check whether the date string is a valid date.
        if (DateTime.TryParse(form["StatusRangeFrom"], out date))
        {
            model.StatusRangeFrom = date;
        }
        else
        {
            //add the model error.
            ModelState.AddModelError("StatusRangeFrom", $"{form["StatusRangeFrom"]} is not an valid date!");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The postman test result like this:

[image]

Besides, on the server side, there have a `TryValidateModel()` method, it could use to repeat validate the model manually, but in your scenario, since you need to convert the date string to datetime, so I think we could directly use the `DateTime.TryParse()` mehtod. More detail information about using the `TryValidateModel` method, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rerun-validation).

Comment: I had to use the DateTime.TryParseExact function in an if before I could use the Convert.ToDateTime

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity this is what worked:

```
if (form["StatusRangeFrom"].ToString() != "")
 {
   string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
   DateTime dateFromTime;
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(form["StatusRangeFrom"].ToString(), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateFromTime))
     {
         userPreferences.StatusRangeTo = Convert.ToDateTime(form["StatusRangeFrom"]);  // now this doesn't error cause it doesn't get called with a bad date.
     }
   else
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("StatusRangeFrom", "Must be a valid Date.");
     }
  }
```

Zhi Lv got me very close!